# List of initial consonant clusters in English

Tags: english, resource-request, consonant-clusters

At a certain point in a macro I have to determine whether shifting the final consonant(s) of one syllable to the next syllable results in a valid onset. Can anyone point me to a complete list of initial clusters for a given dialect, preferably standard southern UK English? I have looked but am only finding examples (and they're examples of orthographic clusters, when I want IPA). I can make my own list of course but would like to check I haven't missed anything.

Comment: What's wrong with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Onset?

Comment: It implies the possibility of \*tl,dl,bw, it asserts the possibility of \*θl based on *thlipsis* which is a what??

Comment: To OP: do you want orthographic clusters or universally-pronounced clusters?

Comment: @user6726 /bw/ sounds fine to me, e.g. in loans like "bueno" or interjections like "bwuh?"; similarly "abuela" syllabifies as /a.'bwej.lə/. (Though I come from an area with a decently high number of L1 Spanish speakers, which might be influencing things.)

Comment: @user6726 I guess I want "generally-pronounced-in-careful-speech" clusters, ideally.

Comment: @rchivers, so you're looking for "most people", not "some people", right? BBC news uses "standard" English, but they also pronounce "Afghanistan" with [vʁ]. I think the answer depends on why you want to know, because "English" is a social phenomenon, and onset statements are notoriously variable in their treatment of marginalia. Is this for a psycholinguistic test, or a hyphenation routine?

Comment: It's to identify (potentally) ambisyllabic consonants in dictionary entries that show hard syllable boundaries. The entry for Afghanistan would have f/g at the syllable boundary so in the first instance I'd be checking whether [fg] is a valid onset. I want to stick to the dictionary entries except for showing ambisyllabic consonants and any knock-on effects of the changed syllabification. On that basis I don't think I'd want to look at voiced realisations of the /f/, even though it might be said that I am mixing up the phonemic and phonetic levels.

Comment: I list all the rules that regulate the English initial consonant clusters in this answer: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/36430/2689 It doesn't include clusters with [j] since it's problematic to decide whether [j] that follows a consonant is a consonant itself.

Comment: @user6726 - In "Afghanistan", "f" and "gh" belong to different syllables: "Af-gha-nis-tan", "fgh" is not in any onset there.

Comment: @YellowSky That is extremely useful, thanks. It seems to me that in Afghanistan, the f would transfer to the onset of the following syllable if it could (as it does if you take out the g). IOW it's because fg is not a possible initial cluster that this doesn't happen. I can't really relate to the pronunciation with vʁ, but if you were to change the g to an ʁ, I think *that* initial cluster would be possible and therefore the v would transfer.

Comment: @YellowSky I note what you say about v in the other thread but in e.g. Avril it seems to me that the v is transferred and borrowed back so as to become ambisyllabic (https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/120a/HayesAmbisyllabicity.pdf). Same for Aslan, compare Asgard. That doesn't feel like a case of learning a new type of cluster that is alien to English - I think it's done instinctively.

Comment: There's no syllable-initial cluster in ‘Avril’ since the syllabification is ‘Av-ril’. Also, mind that [ʁ] is not a distinct phoneme in English, one can say it whenever one likes, in borrowed words, but there are _no_ two words that are distinguished by [ʁ] or another consonant.

Comment: @YellowSky I disagree with you about Avril. I'm convinced there are many bridging or ambisyllabic consonants in English and Hayes's analysis seems to capture this quite elegantly. If I get the macro up and running properly I should end up with enough examples for any major problems to show up.