# Consonant clusters in English - how many exist exactly?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, pronunciation, phonotactics

I am really struggling to find a complete list of all consonant clusters that are possible in the English language. Can anyone point me in the direction of one?

I have spent hours looking online with only partial success so far, finding a list of initial-position consonant clusters on wikipedia (1). I have not found a list of final position consonant clusters, of which there are more.

Just to clarify, I am interested in phonemic analysis (sounds in spoken English represented by IPA symbols), not digraphs (combinations of letters in written English).

(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Onset

Comment: English has 2 sets of consonant clusters — syllable-initial and syllable-final. Do you need both?

Comment: For the possible syllable-initial clusters see here: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/36430/2689
Not taking into account extreme cases, though.

Comment: Which variety of English? For example, the word "though" may or may not be pronounced with a syllable-final semivowel depending on accent/dialect/whateverect

Comment: *All of them*. It's English. (Sorry...)

Comment: If you include clusters that can exist medially, like the one in _gangster_, the count goes way up. But no English word can start with _ngst_, and only one (borrowed) word can end with it. Initial clusters are _bl, gl, pl, kl, br, dr, gr, pr, tr, kr, spl, spr, str, skr, sp, st, sk, sl, sm, sn, thr, fl, fr, sw, tw, skw, fy, shw_, and _shm_. I think that's all, except for foreign words.

Comment: @jlawler – _Amongst_ doesn't seem to be borrowed.

Comment: @YellowSky I was thinking of _Angst_. I rarely use _among_ in the superlative.

Comment: @jlawler — It's not superlative. Just like _amidst_ and _whilest_, it's formed with adverbial genitive _-s-_, and unetymological (excressent) _-t_.

Answer (score 6):

The same page has a list of final consonant clusters further down: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Coda

However, medial clusters are a third situation, in the sense that the medial clusters that appear in non-compound words are much more restricted than every possible combination of word final + word initial clusters.

If you're trying to list *every* possible cluster, you'll run into the issue of edge cases, often relating to borrowed, non-core vocabulary: is /kʃ/ "possible" word-initially because of the word [Kshatriya](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Kshatriya)?
If you're using a word-list like a dictionary as your data source, then your list of possible clusters will depend on how many and which type of low-frequency words the dictionary-makers choose to include. A more objective way of deciding whether to include edge cases might be to take a large corpus and decide to only include consonant clusters that have above a certain number of occurrences in the corpus. Either approach would presumably "miss" at least some cases like this.

On the other hand, if we're truly concerned with what is *possible* rather than just what happens to exist, we might also need to consider the possibility of "accidental gaps": clusters that are not attested, but that fit the pattern of existing clusters and that appear to be easily pronounceable by English speakers. I'm not sure what a good example of a candidate accidental gap is, but there likely are some.  (Perhaps word-final /lkst/?)

Comment: Excellent answer, getting to the core of the problem that phonotactics are inherently blurry, and things like sonority principles are more rough guidelines than hard rules. Aside from /kʃ/, I would also consider /fʃ/ a valid onset cluster, but not, say, /mg/ – even though I know of no words, even borrowed ones, that begin with either. /lkst/ seems perfectly cromulent in coda as well (you might imagine Shakespeare saying something like _thou milk’st the cow_).

Comment: There's a classic article by John Algeo on [What Consonant Clusters
Are Possible?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.1978.11435661).